# How to know if user like my page or dislike it using FBLikeControl?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios8, facebook-like, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm using Facebook Native Like button from FB-SDK.

When user click like button it redirect him to my Facebook page and ask him to like it or not , when user click on one of these two choice it redirect him to my app again and call

```
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation;
```

So I want to know if user click like,dislike,or back button ?

Is there is any way i can know that , like checking the like button text "like,Liked" ???

```
fbLikeControlView.likeControlStyle = FBLikeControlStyleButton;
fbLikeControlView.objectType=FBLikeControlObjectTypePage;
fbLikeControlView.objectID=currentLocation.facebook_page_url;
[fbLikeBtn addSubview:fbLikeControlView];
```

Comment: Why do you want to know that?

Comment: I need to know if user hit like or not so I can show him next view for example

Comment: Like gating is not allowed

Comment: So there is no callback or delegate ?

Comment: Why do you need a callback to delegate if it is not allowed? You are going to do it anyway?

Comment: @WizKid kk , I wanna give the user 50 points when he like my page from my app , user hit like -> redirect him to my page via fbApp -> hit like or back -> back to my app. i need to know now if he hit like or back so i give him 50 point or not ? or should i hit an Facebook api to check if user liked my page or not ?

Comment: That is like gating which is not allowed

Comment: @WizKid so how should i know if the user like my page or not ? or it is not the mobile issue the server side should handle it ? "server side = my app on Facebook "

Comment: @WizKid what I want is simple , i want to do like all game doing like my page u get 50 point or extra gem ?

Comment: I just said it is not allowed. You want your app banned from Facebook?

Comment: @WizKid thx :D can u tell me what is the different between FBSDKLoginButton & FBLoginView ?

Comment: No idea so no I can't

Comment: @WizKid can u help with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363270/fbsdkloginmanager-loginwithreadpermissions