# FBSDKLoginManager logInWithReadPermissions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm using `FBSDKLoginButton` to allow to user login using `Facebook` and using 
`FBSDKLoginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile",@"email",@"user_likes",@"email",@"user_birthday"];`

to ask for permissions , but I need one more permission which is publish_actions I should use 
`FBSDKLoginManager`

with

```
 logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"user_likes",@"user_birthday"] 
logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
```

but this for some reason affect on my permission "some of my permission are missing check image

**Code:-**

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
                [login logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
                    if (error) {
                        // Process error
                    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                        // Handle cancellations
                    } else {
                        // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
                        // should check if specific permissions missing
                        if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"publish_actions"]) {
                            // Do work
                        }
                    }
                }];

[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"",@"user_likes",@"user_birthday"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // Process error
    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
        // Handle cancellations
    } else {
        // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
        // should check if specific permissions missing
        if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
            // Do work
        }
    }
}];
```

**Result:-**

**it take long time to redirect the user to the permission view ? and not all my permission appear to user **

[image]

**Note:-
I know that warning mean that i need to submit my app to review but this not what i'm asking about right now .**

**Update**

**When I Tried "Dheeraj Singh" solution but in this case user will be re-direct twice to the Facebook first time to get publish_action then to get email and birthday permission which is bad.**

Comment: Dude for this you need to put your facebook application in the review. Facebook will review your request and approve or reject your application. And for publish_permission you need to also put your application with the permission request for the review. After reviewing this you can post the data via your facebook application.

Comment: @V.J.  I did and they approved it , but this is not my point . I'm asking why it redirect the user twice to get permission. it should redirect him once and ask for all permissions.

Comment: Can you please give me a list of permission which are approved by facebook.?

Comment: You also need to get approval for "user_likes" and "user_birthday" permissions.

Comment: Hey @Omraj is your problem has resolved or not..?

Comment: Hi @Omarj 
I am facing the same problem. Did you find the solution for it?

Comment: Hey @Omarj did you solved re-direct twice issue?

Answer (score 12):

Facebook Login provides your app access to a person's public profile, friend list, and email address. These three permissions do not require review. Instead, your app's users will choose whether they want to grant access to this information.

In order for your app to access additional elements of a person's Facebook profile (read permissions) or to publish content to Facebook on their behalf (write permissions), you will need to submit for review.

Refer to : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review#submitlogin

**Updated :**

Apps should separate the request of read and publish permissions.

```
 FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

    [login logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            // Process error
        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            // Handle cancellations
        } else {
            // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
            // should check if specific permissions missing
            if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"publish_actions"]) {
                // Do work

                [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"user_likes",@"user_birthday"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
                    if (error) {
                        // Process error
                    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                        // Handle cancellations
                    } else {
                        // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
                        // should check if specific permissions missing
                        if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"user_birthday"]) {
                            // Do work

                            NSLog(@"Permission  2: %@",result.grantedPermissions);
                        }
                    }
                }];

            }
        }
    }];
```

You don't need public_profile in read permission as if granted permission to publish_actions it also gets permission for public_profile.

Comment: i'm not asking about Review warring :D , what I'm asking about is why user_birthday   or email permission did not appear when I add  logInWithPublishPermissions method ????

Comment: Apps separates the request of read and publish permissions. so it was not available to you

Comment: kk I got it , i need only publish_actions and it will handle the public_profile but what about the respond time ?
it take 10sec to call the handler , u can try it with simple project nth just call the login handle and u will see what I mean

Comment: Yes it takes time but it is only way i think to get additional permissions also mentioned in documentation :https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.3#login-additional-permissions

Comment: I just test your code and it is call the permission view twice :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74248/discussion-between-dheeraj-singh-and-omarj).

Comment: so how to do get the users email when you want to use it ?

Comment: Perfect
"You don't need public_profile in read permission as if granted permission to publish_actions it also gets permission for public_profile."

Answer (score 6):

As i seen you code that you are trying to use the "**user_likes**", "**user_birthday**", "**public_profile**" and "**publish_actions**" permissions.

From 1st May 2015 facebook has only enabled "**public_profile**", "email" and "**user_friends**" are available without the approval process.

For "**user_likes**", "**user_birthday**" and "**publish_actions**" you need to get approval from the **facebook**.

For review process you can get help from [Facebook Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature).

Answer (score 4):

I also have the same issue with user_posts permission for two weeks, but after some search i found the solution for this, if you still having this issue follow these steps

1. Go to http://developers.facebook.com and logged in to your developer account.
2. Select your app and go to Roles section.
3. Add a tester in Testers section.
4. Then re-install the app and login using that tester account.
5. Now you try to get the required permissions from tester and tester will see all the permissions list.

Comment: i dont think so, sometimes i got birthday without review. But today i cant, dont know

Answer (score 1):

```
var login = FBSDKLoginManager()


@IBAction func fbBtnPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    login.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self) { (FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult, Error) in

        if Error != nil {
            print("O Login via Facebook Falhou. Erro: \(Error)")
        } else {
            let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString
            self.gotoScreen() //Function for screen after login succesfull 
            print("Acesso concedido ao Facebook. \(accessToken)")
        }

    }

}
```